# How do I create an EDL (Edit Decision List) file using SMPlayer

Tags: mplayer, video-editing

I'm trying to find out how to create a .edl (Edit Decision List) file using [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/). I know how to do it using [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/edl.html) (i.e. mplayer -edlout file.edl). But I can't figure it out for SMPlayer.

All I could find is how to play a video using an .edl file:
http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=271

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out. In Smplayer, got to preferences, click on "Advanced" then the "Options for Mplayer tab, and enter the command just like you would in mplayer. "-edlout .edl"

Next Go to the "advanced" tab and check "Run Mplayer in its own window."

Click apply, then Ok and restart smplayer. When you click on the mplayer window and the focus is on that window it should respond to the "i" key.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks Caleb. The only other thing I would add is that you want to enter the full path to the edl file. Without the full path I couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt appear to work on the following:

SMPlayer: Version: 0.8.0. Using Qt 4.8.3 (compiled with Qt 4.8.1)
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7
Xubuntu 12.10 - 3.5.0-45-generic

Preferences > Advanced > Options for MPlayer > Options

```
-edlout "/home/oliver/Superman2.edl"
```

and "Run Mplayer in its own window" enabled and focus on mplayer window when video is playing, pressing "i" does not create an EDL file.

Running mplayer from the CLI does however create an EDL file:

```
mplayer "/media/dlink2/TV/Superman II.mkv" -edlout "/home/oliver/TV/Superman.edl"
```

Comment: Yes, you might want to upgrade. I just verified it in version 0.8.3
Using Qt 4.8.4 (compiled with Qt 4.8.4) Using MPlayer SVN r34540